# Showing successmessage after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

To show my success message I am using the jQuery fadeOut method to fade.But i want to make it visible for some time and then fadeout.

```
$('#foo').fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

use  for time delay between fadout and fadein

```
$('#successDiv').fadeIn(500).delay(10000).fadeOut(500).remove();
```

[Delay Reference](http://api.jquery.com/delay)

alternatively

```
$("#successDiv").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut();
```